# Changing treeitem's default arrow icon

Tags: tree, firefox-addon, xul

I have this tree structure in my xul application.

```
<tree>
    <treechildren>
        <treeitem>
            <treerow> 
                 /* some code */
            </treerow>
            <treechildren>
                <treeitem> /* some code */</treeitem>
                <treeitem> /* some code */</treeitem>
            </treechildren>
         </treeitem>
     </treechildren>
</tree>
```

As you xul gurus already know, treeitem that contains treechildren gets an arrow left from the label. Like this:

[image]

What I want to know is how to change this arrow and position it on far right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This arrow is called a "twisty" and it is styled using the [`-moz-tree-twisty` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/Styling_a_Tree#CSS_Selectors_for_the_Tree). The default Windows theme defines the following styles for the tree twisty:

```css
treechildren::-moz-tree-twisty {
  -moz-padding-end: 4px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  width: 9px; /* The image's width is 9 pixels */
  list-style-image: url("chrome://global/skin/tree/twisty-clsd.png");
}

treechildren::-moz-tree-twisty(open) {
  width: 9px; /* The image's width is 9 pixels */
  list-style-image: url("chrome://global/skin/tree/twisty-open.png");
}
```

By overriding these styles you change its width and margins, you can also use other images. However, I don't think that you can go as far as to move it to a different position.

Comment: I have aligned twisty to right by putting margin-left to it, and somehow it worked. Thank you very much for your help